# Insert special characters in javascript alert message from server side(asp.net)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, special-characters

I was wondering why this code doesn't work, (as I have no exceptions during debug) when I insert special characters in my message variable like "'" or ",". Whereas everything works well when the message variable does not contains these characters.

For example, this code will works (message="message") :

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string message = "message";
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "alert from codebehind", string.Format("alert('{0}')", message), true);
    }
```

But this won't, I will have no alert window when I will click on the corresponding button (message="message ' message"):

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string message = "message ' message";
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "alert from codebehind", string.Format("alert('{0}')", message), true);
    }
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use special by add back slash

You are debugging server side code. Your javascript runs on client side. You should not expect it to throw exception while debugging server side code. If you want special characters use back slash. Like this

```
 var answer = 'It\'s alright';
 var answer = "He is called \"Johnny\""
```